# Select value in mysql but check another database at clause WHERE

Tags: mysql, database, select

I'm trying to select values from a database, but I need to check another value in another database .

I created this code, but only get 1 result and I don't know why:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `mc_region` 
    WHERE `is_subregion` = 'false' 
        AND lastseen < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 DAY 
        AND (SELECT id_region FROM mc_region_flags 
                    WHERE flag <> 'expire' 
                    AND id_region = mc_region.id
            ) 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

What I've  made wrong?

@Edit
I think I know why this code is not working. At database mc_region_flags not all records from the primary database has flag.

I would like to do the following:

1º Select all records on the first database, where is not subregion and lastseen is more than 20 day
2º Check if any result on the 1st database has flag 'expire', if yes, they are not included in the result.

I cant do this in 1 only SQL Code?

@Edit2

I created this code that simulate `FULL JOIN` but seems that `WHERE` is not work

```
SELECT *
    FROM mc_region AS r RIGHT OUTER JOIN
         mc_region_flags AS f ON r.id = f.id_region
UNION ALL
    SELECT * from 
        mc_region AS r LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        mc_region_flags AS f
        ON r.id = f.id_region
WHERE r.is_subregion = 'false' 
AND f.flag = 'exipre' 
AND r.lastseen < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 DAY
```

Problems WHERE not work

1. `f.flag` is not 'expire'
2. `f.lastseen` is not > 20 days

[image: results]

Comment: I think you mean you are trying to select from two different tables in one query (_NOT_ a different database?) Is that right?

Comment: Not, I want select all of fist, but only if the flag database don't have a flag, with the same region id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `mc_region` AS r LEFT JOIN 
       `mc_region_flags` AS f ON r.`id` = f.`id_region`
 WHERE r.`is_subregion` = 'false' AND 
       r.`lastseen` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 DAY AND
       COALESCE(f.`flag`, '-') <> 'expire'
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Comment: This worked, but I saw that the code was going wrong for what I needed, I edited the question.

Comment: Maybe `IF (f.flag <> 'expire', f.flag IS NULL)`. `f.flag IS NULL` is for those who do not have flag. Will work?

Comment: @LucasFernando See updated answer. If it doesn't do what you expect consider to post your DDL (CREATE TABLE statements) for both tables and sample data from them

Comment: The code is joining only that have records on `mc_region_flags`, if not have a record on there, will not return on the 1st database.

Comment: Not work too :(, I Think that I will not only use mysql to select that regions. I will use Java, and then check that are loaded on there. But Thanks for help me

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Anyway if you can post dumps with respresentative samples of data for both tables here in original post or in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) we'll definitely figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Before the inner nested select add :
    id in (select...)